# What am I doing to cause an "IllegalArgumentException: Negative time" exception in install4j?

Tags: install4j

I've started building Linux installers on the 64 bit windows version of Install4j recently and am getting the error below when it the generated installers start to do their extraction.

Is this something I'm doing wrong or is unsupported?  Or a bug in 5.1 of install4j.  I've recently upgraded to it as well.

```
Extracting files ...
  yx￯N                                                                 
An error occurred:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
Error log: /tmp/install4jError8217531393990762392.log
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
    at java.io.File.setLastModified(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.fileinst.FileInstaller.install(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you use the file installation API in Context? With that you could specify a file options object with a negative time. Otherwise I don't see where the negative time could come from. Maybe the installer is corrupted?

Comment: No I'm not using that api.  I do believe the installer is corrupted. But it seems to be generating a corrupted one from the start somehow.  I'll try to get more info for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to simply be a corrupted custom JRE being included in the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Due to an independent reason one of the files contained in the source directory had a file date in the year 1961.

Since most calenders starts at 198ß a check of that results in a negative timestamp.
After setting a current date the build process worked fine.
So it was not denepending on any version of jdk and had nothing to do with any broken jre installations or something like that.

Hint: In the windows exploerer no file date was shown. This might be helpful for anyone having a similar source file since you won't notice a wrong date as long you don't see it.
Search for file with dates before 1980 or use a commander should help you to find that ones.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me in intellij is setting
Project Structure --> Language Level == SDK Default (8 -Lambdas....)